# Expand Tuple in Angular Component Members

Tags: angular, typescript, tuples

In React there is a way of creating state variables like this:

```
const SomeComponent = ({ someProp }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<boolean>(false);
}
```

Is it possible to achieve the same spread of a tuple inside the members of an Angular component?

For example:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDirective]'
})
export class AppDirective {
  [value, observable] = createState<boolean>(false);
}
```

The problem here is that `[value, observable]` is not a valid syntax. Replacing it with
`a = createState<boolean>(false)` works, but I am looking for a way to expand the tuple into two member variables of the directive.
Note that `createState` returns `[BehaviorSubject<T>, Observable<T>]`.

Comment: const [value, observable] = createState<boolean>(false) ahould work..?

Answer (score 0):

the closest option to what you tried to write would be

```
export class AppDirective {
  someState = createState<boolean>(false);
  value = someState[1];
  subject = someState[0];
}
```

but It seems you are using unpopular library that will just make you suffer instead of developing. Angular provides a handy two way bindings, that you should use instead:

```
value = 'justValue, Nothing more required';
```

component.html:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value">
```

Answer (score 0):

Function implementation can not be compared with class definition. To define destructuring for class properties, you may do so inside some function class as below:

```js
function createState<T>(initialState: T): [BehaviorSubject<T>, Observable<T>] {
  const app = new BehaviorSubject<T>(initialState);
  return [app, app.asObservable()];
}

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  value!: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
  observable!: Observable<boolean>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    [this.value, this.observable] = createState<boolean>(false);
    const [value, observable] = createState(false);
  }
}
```